# Recursive function to repeat string in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I am absolute OCaml beginner. I want to create a function that repeats characters 20 times.
This is the function, but it does not work because of an error.

```
let string20 s =
  let n = 20 in
  s ^ string20 s (n - 1);;

string20 "u";;
```

I want to run like this

```
# string20 "u"
- : string = "uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu"
```

Comment: You should think about the stop condition of your recursive function first. Then you should know the syntax to apply in ocaml for declaring a recursive function (this is ocaml course level).

Comment: Can you please put in the error you're receiving?

Comment: Bit off topic, but `String.make 20 'u'` does the job.

Comment: `string20` accepts a single argument `s`, but was provided `s` and `n-1` on second call and afterward.

Comment: You edited this question beyond recognition to something that is considered off topic here on SO so i rolled it back as the original question has several good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `string20` takes one parameter but you are calling it recursively with 2 parameters.

The basic ideas are in there, but not quite in the right form. One way to proceed is to separate out the 2-parameter function as a separate "helper" function. As @PierreG points out, you'll need to delcare the helper function as a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

1. Recursive functions in Ocaml are defined with `let rec`
2. As pointed out in the comments you've defined your function to take one parameter but you're trying to recursively call with two.

You probably want something like this:

```
let rec stringn s n =
  match n with
  1 -> s
| _ -> s ^ stringn s (n - 1)
;;
```

Comment: naming `stringn` is quite redundant, since Ocaml functions are curried you can just do something like `let stringN = string N in stringN "foo"`

Answer (score 0):

```
let rec string n s =
  if n = 0 then "" else s ^ string (n - 1) s

let string20 = string 20
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a common pattern to separate a function into a "fixed" part and inductive part. In this case, a nested helper function is needed to do the real recursive work in a new scope while we want to fix an input string `s` as a constant so we can use to append to `s2`. `s2` is an accumulator that build up the train of strings over time while `c` is an inductor counting down to 1 toward the base case.

```
let repeat s n = 
  let rec helper s1 n1 = 
    if n1 = 0 then s1 else helper (s1 ^ s) (n1 - 1)
  in helper "" n
```

A non-tail call versions is more straightforward since you won't need a helper function at all:

```
let rec repeat s n = 
  if n = 0 then "" else s ^ repeat s (n - 1)
```

On the side note, one very fun thing about a functional language with first-class functions like Ocaml is currying (or partial application). In this case you can create a function named `repeat` that takes two arguments `n` of type `int` and `s` of type `string` as above and partially apply it to either `n` or `s` like this:

```
# (* top-level *)
# let repeat_foo = repeat "foo";;
# repeat_foo 5;;
- : bytes = "foofoofoofoofoo"   (* top-level output *)
```

if the `n` argument was labeled as below:

```
let rec repeat ?(n = 0) s = 
      if n = 0 then "" else s ^ repeat s (n - 1)
```

The order of application can be exploited, making the function more flexible:

```
# (* top-level *)
# let repeat_10 = repeat ~n:10;;
# repeat_10 "foo";;
- : bytes = "foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo" (* top-level output *)
```

See my post [Currying Exercise in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@jochasinga/currying-for-a-greater-good-68329e0c015f) (though it is in JavaScript but pretty simple to follow) and this [lambda calculus primer](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lambda-calculus/#MulArgOpe).

Comment: To actually work, your tail-recursive `helper` ought to better return `s2` in the base case and be invoked with `""` instead of `s`. Also, `s1` is redundant. And where is the label `~n` in your last example coming from?

Comment: @AndreasRossberg yes thank you for the correction. I also added the labeled argument version for better clarity.

Comment: I believe the call to `helper` is still wrong. You need to invoke it with the empty string, otherwise you're off by one.